# Encrypt a file and save as the same file

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption

I need to encrypt my xml file and save it as the same file.
For example: I have an xml file test.xml, which i need to encrypt and save as test.xml.
I use the following code:

```
public static void Encrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
        {
               string EncryptionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncDesKey"];
                var inputFile = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
                {
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

                    using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            int data;
                            while ((data = inputFile.ReadByte()) != -1)
                            {
                                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

However, I get the error that the file is still in use by another process, which i understand. But I have not been able to figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: You could use a temporary intermediary file or an array. Not an ideal solution, but everything should work.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid using a temp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the File.ReadAllBytes(Path) method, you can essentially cache the contents of the file into a variable then close the file (which releases the lock)

Try this:

```
public class Encryption
{
    public void Encrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
    {
        string encryptionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncDesKey"];
        var inputData = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilePath);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    foreach (var item in inputData)
                    {
                        cs.WriteByte(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```